# HttpRequest with multiple parameters swift

Tags: swift, xcode, httprequest

I'm trying to create a request with multiple parameters using Swift. So far I managed to create with one parameter but not with multiple.

I tried to use a Dictionary but couldn't do it.

Here is my actual code:

```
let protocolo = txtProtocolo.text!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
let parameters = "protocolo=\(protocolo)    "

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request)
      { (data, response, error) in
....
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
let dictionary = ["protocolo":protocolo,
                  "secondParameter": "value"]
```

And use this dictionary as httpBody.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send form data in POST request in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492089/how-to-send-form-data-in-post-request-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the option use Alamofire. It is very good :)

But if you want to use the dictionary. It seems you have to convert it to a string. Did you try something like

```
let parameters = ["auth":"asdf", "width":"123"]

let parametersString = (parameters.compactMap({ (key, value) -> String in
    return "\(key)=\(value)"
}) as Array).joined(separator: "&")
```

And use the parametersString as the parameter

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

I'm using dictionary because I thought it would be the best solution for what I'm trying to do. I'm building this generic method to do httpRequests that will receive the parameters on a dictionary. I'm developing in swift only for 4 days, so I don't if there is a better solution :)

Comment: If I where you I would look at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire. Its a way more smooth and simple way of doing httpRequests, instead of using URLSession.shared.dataTask. But that's just my personal opinion!

Comment: I was using it but I couldn't map the response to my model. I was probably doing something weird. I'll try it again. Thanks!