# Swift Posting to .net core with Post Method Not Working, Getting not Authorized Back From response

Tags: c#, ios, .net, swift

I'm completely stuck. I've tried everything. I was given this code snippet for .net i believe:

```
[HttpGet, HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> getInfo(string number, string authToken, string profileName)
```

and I've been trying to get a post request with it to work. GET works fine, however I have a call where i need to upload an iFile form and I figure if I get the post call working with the other methods parameters I should be able to get this.

I tried:

```
let params = ["number": number, "authToken" : authToken, "profileName" : profileName]
    
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: fullURL)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(params)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request) {//...}
```

What Can I Do To Make this Work? Am I missing information? Because I need to be able to POST to this:

```
[Route("uploadImage")]
[HttpGet, HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> uploadImage(List<IFormFile> files, string authToken, string number, string profileName, int profileNum, string ID)
```

Comment: That's just a function declaration in C#, we don't know how it's done. Does it accept JSON? Usually token are set in header, not in body.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send form data in POST request in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492089/how-to-send-form-data-in-post-request-in-swift-3). You need to send your content as form-data and not as json. The linked question provides you with the details needed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an error with the API endpoint not properly receiving data, and that my form was correct. Using Postman I was able to conclude the error wasn't on my end and the API team was called in and fixed the issue.